# Can pescetarians eat butter?

Tags: dairy-products, pescetarianism

Can I eat butter? I can use olive oil in some dishes, but sometimes I need butter. I'm new to pescetarianism, so I still don't know all the rules.

Comment: You can set your own rules.  There are no vegetarian police who will arrest you for eating the wrong things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both vegetarians and pescetarians eat dairy and eggs, it is just that pescetarians eat also fish and seafood.

Comment: Exactly.  It's only vegans that avoid butter.  Vegans: no animal products, vegetarians: no products that require killing animals, but other animal products are all right, pescetarian: vegetarian except also fish.  Good luck!  And welcome to the site.